# How to set up apache server remotely on EC2 instance using Chef

Tags: ruby, apache, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am currently using chef-solo to run the following code that sets up a simple apache web server with the following code:

```
service 'httpd' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end

file '/var/www/html/index.html' do
  content '<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Apache server.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I run the command `sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json` to run this code. The server runs as expected locally. *I now want to be able to deploy and provision the apache server on an EC2 instance I already have set up and can access over SSH*. **What amendments do I need to make to my code in order to make this happen?**

Please ask if you need any more clarity in what I'm asking for. Thanks in advance.

Content of solo.rb:

```
file_cache_path "/var/chef/cache"
cookbook_path "/home/caleb.whittington/chef-repo"
```

Content of web.json:

```
{
  "run_list": [ "recipe[apache]" ]
}
```

Comment: If the EC2 server has access to internet to download files. The cookbook would do the needful, given OS is supported with the cookbook.

Comment: Yes my EC2 can access the internet and the OS is compatible with my cookbook

Comment: Then It should be seamless.